# How do you pass a numpy array to openCV without saving the file as a png or jpeg first?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to take a screenshot, then convert it to a numpy array. I then want to run cv2.matchTemplate using the screenshot. So far the only way I have gotten this to work is to save the image: cv2.imwrite('temp.png',imcv) and then use that image in cv2.matchTemplate. This seems horribly wrong. How can I convert the numpy array properly to avoid saving and just pass it straight to the cv2.matchTemplate function?

I am doing this project in Ubuntu btw.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import PIL
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# part of the screen
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(65,50,835,725)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2

#convert to numpy array
im=im.convert('RGB')
imcv = np.array(im) 
imcv = imcv[:, :, ::-1].copy() 
cv2.imwrite('temp.png',imcv)

img = cv2.imread('temp.png',0)
template = cv2.imread('fight.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

# Apply template Matching
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
print(min_val)
print(max_val)
print(min_loc)
print(max_loc)
if(max_loc == (484,125)):
    print("True!")

top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.suptitle(cv2.TM_CCOEFF)

plt.show()
```

This is the simplest I can get it down too: I will also post error message after code.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import PIL
import cv2
import numpy

im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(65,50,835,725)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
print type(im)
im=im.convert('RGB')
print type(im)
im = numpy.array(im)
print type(im)
im = im[:, :, ::-1].copy() 
print type(im)
cv2.cv.fromarray(im)
print type(im) 

template = cv2.imread('fight.png',0)

templateTest = cv2.matchTemplate(im,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
print(min_val)
print(max_val)
print(min_loc)
print(max_loc)

<type 'instance'>
<type 'instance'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((img.depth() == CV_8U || img.depth() == CV_32F) && img.type() == templ.type()) in matchTemplate, file /home/kninja/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp, line 249
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StartOVer.py", line 32, in <module>
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(im,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
cv2.error: /home/kninja/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:249: error: (-215) (img.depth() == CV_8U || img.depth() == CV_32F) && img.type() == templ.type() in function matchTemplate
```

Comment: I found my error!!!! The template image was in grayscale and the screenshot with rgb. The image must match for the function matchTemplate to work!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import PIL
import cv2
import numpy

im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(65,50,835,725)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
print type(im)
im=im.convert('RGB')
print type(im)
im = numpy.array(im)
print type(im) 

cv_img = im.astype(np.uint8)
cv_gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread("filename.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a similar project. I have been using the pyautogui library for automation, but was discontent with the image matching functions provided by the library, due to the long run time and inflexibility of exact image matching, so I switched to opencv for template matching. I found this post seeking to produce a grey numpy array screenshot in the fastest possible manner. Froyo's answer does not write to the hard drive, but I have found what I have in place is faster anyways. I am also running on Ubuntu, and I believe the screenshot taken by pyautogui is called on the backend using the popular linux tool scrot. The following code snippet is modified from sample code provided in opencv's documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import PIL
from time import time, sleep
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def click_image(template_filename):
    start = time()
    '''
    im=ImageGrab.grab()
    im=im.convert('RGB')
    im = np.array(im)
    cv_img = im.astype(np.uint8)
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    '''
    pyautogui.screenshot('current_screen.png')
    screen = cv2.imread('current_screen.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    template = cv2.imread(template_filename,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    if template is None:
        print("failed to load template.")
        quit()
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]
    method = 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF'
    meth = eval(method)
    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(screen,template,meth)
    #get min/max values to match
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    center =((top_left[0]+bottom_right[0])/2(top_left[1]+bottom_right[1])/2)
    print(center)
    pyautogui.moveTo(center)
    pyautogui.click(center,button="right")
    end = time()
    print("clicked in "+str(int(1000*(end-start)))+"ms")
click_image("files.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This only applies to old version of OpenCV. In recent versions of OpenCV the images are already stored as numpy arrays, so `fromarray()` is no longer required.*

#### Original 2014 answer:

PIL images support the array interface, so use `fromarray`:

```
cv2.cv.fromarray(imcv)
```

Comment: This is the error I get when I try that: File "anotherTest.py", line 22, in <module>
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
TypeError: image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: When I try cv2.imread(imcv) it gives me this error:  image = cv2.imread(imcv)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, numpy.ndarray found   Does that help at all? I will continue to research numpy.ndarray

Comment: So the problem is not with the command you suggested, cv2.matchTemplate won't accept it as a parameter, even though it says that is what it wants, and when I print type(im) it says it is a numpy array.

Comment: Just results in `AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv'`

Comment: @ruohola  Not in 2014 it didn't.  :)  But now it's no longer needed, see [What is the replacement of cv2.cv.fromarray in opencv 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43923669/674039) about that.  I've edited the answer to point this out.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to convert:

```
import cv2
import PIL
import numpy as np

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```