# What is the replacement of cv2.cv.fromarray in opencv 3.2?

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am writing a face recognition program and the reference that I got from web was using previous OpenCV version. I am using OpenCV 3.2.0 build from source. In the reference to put the name just below the face in a video. My reference code looks like

```
cv2.putText(cv2.cv.fromarray(img), str(id), (x, y + h), font, 2, 255);
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the Python API for OpenCV images are `numpy` arrays so `fromarray()` is not required (if available at all in the `cv` module).

See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) for an example. You can just pass `img` to `cv2.putText()`.